# Magento 2 with Nginx and Varnish - How to serve webp images

Tags: nginx, varnish, magento, images

I am using the following, trying to serve webp images from Magento using Nginx and Varnish as caching.

Added to /etc/nginx/mime.types

```
 image/webp webp;
```

Added to main nginx.conf

```
http {
map $http_accept $webp_suffix {
            default   "";
            "~*webp"  ".webp";
          }
}
```

Added to my-site.conf for Magento 2 server block

```
location /media/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;

        location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|webp)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            expires +1y;
            try_files $uri$webp_suffix $uri$webp_suffix/ /get.php?$args;
            
        }
```

But I still get jpg images instead of webp. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are the exact filenames on your server?

Comment: Do you mean the images filenames? It's like /media/catalog/product/cache/717232bbf8aac833c3a57552fb3b4c68/r/o/rose-gold-cuff-bracelet-1.jpg. In the same path I also have the webp extension of the image.

Comment: What is the filename of `.webp` version?

Comment: It's media/catalog/product/cache/717232bbf8aac833c3a57552fb3b4c68/r/o/rose-gold-cuff-bracelet-1.webp

Answer (score 2):

When the `map` is defined like:

```
map $http_accept $webp_suffix {
    default       "";
    "~image/webp" ".webp";
}
```

And when the `try_files` is:

```
try_files $uri$webp_suffix $uri$webp_suffix/ /get.php$args;
```

It means that when request URI is `/media/image.jpg`, nginx will look for `image.jpg.webp` if user's HTTP `Accept` header contains `image/webp`.

So, you need to append the `.webp` extension to all your image file names, instead of replacing the extension.

Edit:

For this to work on any caching server beyond original server, the cache needs to cache different versions of the URL.

To accomplish this, one needs to add

```
add_header Vary Accept;
```

to nginx configuration. This tells the upstream cache that it should store different of the URL based on user's `Accept` header.

So, in your case, Varnish should be configured to obey the `Accept` header.

Cloudflare is another problem. It does not support `Vary: Accept` header at all, so this approach of serving WebP images does not work with Cloudflare out of the box.

It can be worked around by adding a Cloudflare worker, which extracts the `Accept` header from the requests, and defines cache keys based on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaning the issue!

Comment: @NikosKlavdianos you will also need to amend changes to your Varnish VCL in order to vary cache based on the presence of webp in Accept: client headers. Otherwise, Varnish will just cache the first time accessed image type (depending on what the first loading client supports webp or not)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am still struggling to load the webp images. I think it's the Cloudflare I use and I'll remove that from the stack. Could you be more specific about default.vcl?

Comment: I updated my answer to include more information about caching.

Comment: https://findwork.dev/blog/caching-tricks-with-cloudflare-workers/ is a good starting point for creating Cloudflare worker. It deals with mobile / desktop choice, but the core concept is the same.